# Ruby on Rails: How to get tweets from the next_page using the Twitter search Api? And What should be my since_id and max_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter

Here is my code. I am trying to get the next page of results with `@second_results`. But it seems to just duplicate whatever is received from @first_results.

```
search = TwitterManualSearch.new


@first_results = search.first_query(:tag => params[:search]).results

@second_results = search.second_query(:tag => params[:search], :since_id =>  @first_results.results.last.id, :max_id => @first_results.max_id).results
```

For your reference I wrote some method to ease out the calls and I am using the twitter gem here - https://github.com/sferik/twitter

I know i am doing something fundamentally wrong but what is it?

Update: to give you a brief, rough and quick idea, this how I am using the code to return the results (excluding all my methods)

To get first batch of results I do

```
@first_results = Twitter.search("#tag", :count => 30, :result_type => "recent")

@first_results.results.map do |status|
  "#{status.from_user}: #{status.text}"
end
```

Then later to get more results

```
    @second_results = search.second_query("#tag", :count => 30, :result_type => "recent", :since_id =>  @first_results.results.last.id, :max_id => @first_results.max_id).results



@second_results.map do |status|
  "#{status.from_user}: #{status.text}"
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you give the full context of where you are calling this and what the methods that you wrote to ease out the calls are?

Comment: I have updated the question. If I remove my method/classes the update code is what it pretty much does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this https://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines. What you are doing doesnt differentiate between the first instance variable and the second instance variable. Instead, just make sure to put a count on the first variable call and match the `max_id` of your second call with the last id of the first instance variable call. Something like this

```
@second_results = search.second_query(:tag => params[:search], :max_id => @first_results.results.last.id).results
```

And you should be fine. Though watch out for redundancies.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this in a controller your going to end up with a "To many API Calls" error being returned from twitter. Your going to need to create a rake task that pulls in all your needed tweets in a way that doesn't exceed their rate limits.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1

I am guessing that what you are seeing might be a result of exceeding their limits.

Comment: I am doing this via ajax, a controller and whole separate clas. I am taking care of the limits. Plus i need to know how to get to next page anyways. Having rake isnt an option here :). And i am pretty sure same content shown twice isnt going over rate limit. I am doing something wrong with the handling the max and since id.