# Using cURL command with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, api, twitter

Want to scrape a bunch of tweets via the Twitter API, as an output I get cURL command, something like that

```
curl --get 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json' --data 'q=football' --header      'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="**hidden**", oauth_nonce="**hidden**", oauth_signature="**hidden**", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="**hidden**", oauth_token="**hidden**", oauth_version="1.0"' --verbose
```

My question, is there a way to use this command into a Ruby script to scrape the tweets ?

Comment: Why not use the [`Ruby Twitter API`](https://github.com/sferik/twitter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Twitter gem available here http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter with the following code you can get all the tweets from a ruby script.

```
require 'twitter'

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
    config.consumer_key        ="hidden"
    config.consumer_secret     ="hidden"
    config.access_token        ="hidden"
    config.access_token_secret ="hidden"
end

client.search("football").collect do |tweet|
    puts tweet.text
end
```

Comment: Trust me, you made my life better :) just one last thing, is there a way to extract, let's say, about thousands tweets instead of the existing (about hundreds)? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Using the max_id parameter and the id of the last tweet you can get the next hundred batch.  The following answer should be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/15734833/133197

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap it in backticks and get the output like from any unix(like) command

script.rb

```
cmd=`echo 'hello world'`
puts cmd
```

ouptput: hello world

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use existing [API](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) as @Hunter McMillen had suggested, but if you want to perform http-requests yourself, you can use [net/http](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net%3a%3aHTTP-label-GET+with+Dynamic+Parameters) lib. Example below:

```
require 'net/http'
uri = URI('http://example.com/index.html')
params = { :limit => 10, :page => 3 }
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)

res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
puts res.body if res.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
```

[Here is the info on how to set headers](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net%3a%3aHTTP-label-Setting+Headers).